# android webdriver enabled but not responding - debugging? - emulator on headless ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, selenium, android-emulator, webdriver

### Config

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64bits
CPU: Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2352, 2.1GHz
RAM: 2GB
Headless Ubuntu, I use Xvfb, without Eclipse
android: v4.2.2 & webdriver v2.32.0

### Question

As you can see in next steps, the emulator is initialized and the Webdriver is loaded and enabled.
However the Android Webdriver isn't responding to a browser connection at the URL:

```
http://myremoteserver:8080/wd/hub
```

So is there a way to debug the Webdriver (eg: monitor its activity from the emulator shell)?
Concerning stackoverflow I read questions tagged with [android] [android-emulator] [webdriver] [selenium] , unfortunately I get no answer.
I also checked on the Android Developer Google Group.
I tried to be as precise as possible but if you need more informations, don't hesitate to ask me. Tx!

### Detailed steps

*shell commands are preceded by `$`

shell STDOUT are preceded by `>`*

- launch a virtual X server on screen 99 :

```
$ Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 2>/dev/null &
```

- define $DISPLAY :

```
$ export DISPLAY=:99
```

- download the adt-bundle and unzip the sdk/ dir in ~  and renaming it 'android_sdk'

all the next commands are issued from `~/android_sdk/tools`

- update the sdk:

```
$ ./android update sdk --no-ui
```

- list targets :

```
$ ./android list targets
```

I identified that the appropriate target is the number 25:

```
> id: 25 or "android-17"
     Name: Android 4.2.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 17
     Revision: 2
     Skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA, WQVGA432, WXGA800-7in, HVGA, WXGA800, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WXGA720
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a, mips, x86
```

- create an emulator :

```
$ ./android create avd -n my_android -t 25 -c 100M --abi armeabi-v7a
```

- launch the emulator :

```
$ ./emulator -avd my_android -no-audio &
> Failed to create Context 0x3005
> emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
```

- check if emulator daemon found by server :

```
$ ../platform-tools/adb devices
> * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
    * daemon started successfully *
    List of devices attached 
    emulator-5554   device
```

- download the latest Webdriver unzip it in 'tools/'
- install the webdriver onto the emulator :

```
$ ../platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 -e install -r  android-server-2.32.0.apk
> Success
```

- launch the Webdriver :

```
../platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity -e debug true
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity (has extras) }
```

- check that the Webdriver package is properly enabled via the emulator shell:

```
$ ../platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554  shell
(from the emulator shell): $ pm list packages -e
> package:org.openqa.selenium.android.app
```

- forward requests :

```
$ ../platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

Comment: Any advance in this? I want to do something similar ... I would love to hear from you.

Comment: This is not a priority for the moment, but I hope I might come back to this.